# Apple search API get Customers Also Bought

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, itunes-search-api

Is there something for the Apple Search API to get Customers Also Bought with the app's id.

I could get the app details, and app reviews but not customers also bought yet.

Comment: How to get app details using search api? Can you post code for that? This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696311/get-game-details-from-itunes-using-php#_=_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the Search API nor the Enterprise Partner Feed which references customer purchases. I doubt they will ever make such information available. If you have an affiliate account you could use your own analytics to track customer purchases.